# What's the problem with this code in Java?

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to make a program in Java in Eclipse, what tell me, if I can make the triangle or not. It is my code:

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class haromszog {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        int a;
        int b;
        int c;

    System.out.print("Please insert the 'a' side of the triangle:");
    a = System.in.read();

    System.out.print("Please insert the 'b' side of the triangle:");
    b = System.in.read();

    System.out.print("Please insert the 'c' side of the triangle:");
    c = System.in.read();

    if ((a+b)>c)
    {
        if ((a+c)>b)
        {
            if ((b+c)>a)
            {System.out.print("You can make this triangle");
            }
            else 
                System.out.print("You can't make this triangle");

        }
    }
    }
}
```

The Eclipse, can run it, but it writes:

> > Please insert the 'a' side of the triangle:  (for example I write: ) 5
> >
> > Please insert the 'b' side of the triangle:
> >
> > Please insert the 'c' side of the triangle:
>
> You can't make this triangle

And I can't write anything to the b and c side. What's the problem with this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a triangle with for loops](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11409621/creating-a-triangle-with-for-loops)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`System.in.read()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28%29) reads a single `byte` from standard input of your application. That's *almost certainly* not what you want (unless something is passing binary data to your application).

You could try [`System.console().readLine()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Console.html#readLine%28%29) instead (followed by [`Integer.parseInt()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) to convert the resulting `String` to an `int`).

Comment: It was good, while I didn't write the if expressions, when i wrote them the compiler told error. But thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

From http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html:

> read() : Reads the next byte of data from the input stream.

You read not integer, but char code.

You should probably do:

```
java.util.Scanner s = new java.util.Scanner(System.in); 
int k = s.nextInt();
```

Comment: Probably not the Scanner. He looks to be processing commandline input. In which case, I would probably use readLine() followed by Integer.parseInt() on reader created by new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( System.in ) ).

Comment: @Konstantin Komissarchik what is wrong with `Scanner`? less code to write :)

Comment: If Scanner handles new lines between inputs correctly, then it can also be used.

Comment: @Konstantin: it's "console input" not "commandline input". The latter would imply parameters (i.e. `String[] args`).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the System.in.read() problem, you need to combine your if statements, because that the else clause currently only applies to the inner one.

```
if ((a+b)>c && (a+c)>b && (b+c)>a) { 
   System.out.print("You can make this triangle");
}
else {
   System.out.print("You can't make this triangle");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You read a byte, so if it is the ascii-charcter '5' it is not the number 5, but 53. Your next problem is Carriage-Return which is read as the next byte.

Use the java.util.Scanner class instead:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
int a = sc.nextInt ();
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Joachim's answer, try this:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Please insert the 'a' side of the triangle:");
    int a = s.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Please insert the 'b' side of the triangle:");
    int b = s.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Please insert the 'c' side of the triangle:");
    int c = s.nextInt();

    }
}
```

Comment: It was the best answer for me, because, it can is easy, to a beginner too :) Thanks.