# Displaying a pyramid of number ladder

Tags: java

I did this below but I didn't get it right,

```
int i = 1;
       while(i <= 6){
             for(int j = 1;j <= 6-i;j++){
                   System.out.print("  ");
            }
            for(int m = 1; m <= i; m++){
                   System.out.print(m + " ");
            }
            i++;
            System.out.println();
     }
```

I got this instead :

```
             1
           1 2
         1 2 3
       1 2 3 4
     1 2 3 4 5 
   1 2 3 4 5 6
```

But I need guide on how to get this below,

```
          1
        2 1 2
      3 2 1 2 3
    4 3 2 1 2 3 4
  5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: Not the problem, but why are you using `while` for the outer loop instead of `for`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple java program of pyramid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21373738/simple-java-program-of-pyramid) 
Check this, there is a solution with dollar sign, or for learn check this https://java4732.blogspot.fr/2016/08/pyramid-programs-in-java.html

Comment: I know that it might look tricky, but you are on good way so far, I would suggest you to try a little bit more and do it yourself, you can easily google solution but that isn't how you become good developer because you won't always have solution available.

Comment: Let me hint you, you are able to print half, on each row, so what you need is eg. to add another loop for print second side- you know on the edge will be number "1" right? :)
And you know the max number, which is "i" in your case

Comment: You are, literally, half-way there. Just add another loop at the end, just like the one before, but counting the numbers down in reverse.

Comment: Ah, he need also to swap printed numbers, ok, does not matter, start with printing full pyramid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you have my solution, little smarty solution with using absolute value, with notes why is what where

```
public static void printPyramid(int rows) {
        // row counter
        for (int i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {

            // padding- size = rows - i
            for (int j = 1; j <= rows - i; j++) {
                // 2 spaces - char + space
                System.out.print("  ");
            }

            // print numbers
            for (int j = -i; j <= i; j++) {
                // we want only once 1, and skip print zero
                if (j == 0 || j == 1) {
                    continue;
                }

                // print absolute value
                System.out.print(Math.abs(j) + " ");
            }

            // new row- println same as print("\n");
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

With 6 rows, output is

```
          1 
        2 1 2 
      3 2 1 2 3 
    4 3 2 1 2 3 4 
  5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 
6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Answer (score 5):

```
while(i <= 6){
    for(int j = 1; j <= 6 - i; j++){
        System.out.print("  ");
    }
    for(int m = i-1; m > 1; m--){
        System.out.print(m + " ");
    }
    for(int m = 1; m < i; m++){
        System.out.print(m + " ");
    }

    i++;
    System.out.println();
}
```

This should work for you, i just added / edited this part:

```
    for(int m = i-1; m > 1; m--){
        System.out.print(m + " ");
    }
    for(int m = 1; m < i; m++){
        System.out.print(m + " ");
    }
```

To let it count down again, and let it count up afterwards

Comment: notice he need also to swap numbers, not only the right side of pyramid

Comment: Edited it to be fitting for that

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick, but it's important to understand what is going on:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
            printRow(6, i);
        }
    }

    public static void printRow(int highestValue, int rowValue) {

        for (int i = 0; i < (highestValue - rowValue); i++) {
            System.out.print("  ");
        }

        for (int i = rowValue; i >= 1; i--) {
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        }

        for (int i = 2; i <= rowValue; i++) {
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

The first loop pads the left side of the pyramid, as you have already done. The second loop counts *down* from the value of the row to `1`, which is the center of the pyramid. The third loop counts back *up* from `2` to the value of the row. Note that for the first row, `2` will not be printed, because `i = 2` is greater than `rowValue`, which is `1`, so the loop is skipped.

Running this results in the following:

```
          1 
        2 1 2 
      3 2 1 2 3 
    4 3 2 1 2 3 4 
  5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 
6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Note that a row starting with `6` is printed since I used the bounds you provided. If this is not what should be done (from your example output), I will leave that up to you on how to fix this. Pay attention to the name of the arguments in the `printRow` method to see why there is an extra row printed.

Answer (score 0):

Let's break this down into parts. First we need to figure out how to output a single level of the pyramid. Let's start without padding. For the first level it's just `"1"`, for every other level it's the level above it surrounded by the  "number" of that level (and the spaces).

```
private static String buildLevel(int num) {
    if (num == 1) return "1";

    return Integer.toString(num) + " " + buildLevel(num -1) + " " + Integer.toString(num);
}
```

We then need to be able to add the padding, so let's create a method that pads to a certain length.

```
private static String pad(String stringToPad, int padTo) {
    return String.join("", Collections.nCopies(padTo - stringToPad.length(), " ")) + stringToPad;
}
```

Putting this together we can create a method to build a pyramid by looping over the needed levels and concatenating the levels together.

```
private static String buildPyramid(int height) {
    int expectedLength = height * 2 + 1;

    String out = "";

    for (int i = 1; i <= height; i++) {
        out += pad(buildLevel(i), expectedLength) + "\n";
        expectedLength += 2;
    }

    return out;
}
```

The length of the first line is the `height * 2 + 1`, derived by counting. (This includes two spaces at the beginning of each line, which is in your examples). Each subsequent line should be 2 longer than the one above it.

Call it like this to produce your example

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(buildPyramid(5));
}
```

Outputs:

```
          1
        2 1 2
      3 2 1 2 3
    4 3 2 1 2 3 4
  5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5
```

For completeness, here is all the code in one block.

```
private static String buildLevel(int num) {
    if (num == 1) return "1";

    return Integer.toString(num) + " " + buildLevel(num -1) + " " + Integer.toString(num);
}

private static String pad(String stringToPad, int padTo) {
    return String.join("", Collections.nCopies(padTo - stringToPad.length(), " ")) + stringToPad;
}

private static String buildPyramid(int height) {
    int expectedLength = height * 2 + 1;

    String out = "";

    for (int i = 1; i <= height; i++) {
        out += pad(buildLevel(i), expectedLength) + "\n";
        expectedLength += 2;
    }

    return out;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(buildPyramid(6));
}
```