# Printing Reverse Triangle with Numbers - Java

Tags: java, for-loop, geometry

I have some problem printing a **reverse triangle** I want to achieve, like this pattern:

```
******
***
*
```

But my goal is to achieve that pattern with this **numbers**:

```
333221
221
1
```

So, this is my code so far:

```
int x = 1;
for(int r=0;r<3;r++)
{
    x=x+r;
    for(int c=0;c<x;c++)
    {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    x+=1;
    System.out.println();
}
```

Which the output is **upright** like this:

```
*
***
******
```

I want to make the pattern **reverse** with the numbers as it shown above.

Can anyone give me some idea how to deal with it? Thanks!

Comment: revers loop. change value of `x` and decrement `x` instead of incrementing it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a triangle with for loops](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11409621/creating-a-triangle-with-for-loops)

Comment: I don't get what you mean, can you clarify it? sorry I'm beginner here.

Comment: @WilliamPrice No, I'm not creating a `equilateral` triangle.

Comment: @Paul19 possible duplicate not because it's exactly the same but because the _concepts_ and principles are similar and should be able to lead you in the right direction instead of us answering (what looks like) a homework question.

Comment: someone [already done it here](http://ideone.com/qZVoKV)

Comment: @WilliamPrice I know and I already visited it this passed few days but I don't get the concept and logic of mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how i would do it:

```
    for (i = 3; i > 0; i--) {

        for (j = i; j > 0; j--) {

            for (c = j; c > 0; c--) {

                System.out.print(j);
            }
        }
        System.out.println();

    }
```

- first loop: you want to print 3 lines;
- second loop: each line has i distinct numbers
- third loop: print number j j times

Comment: Yes! Perfect! This is actually I want to achieve, thank you very much! :D

Answer (score 0):

You just need to reverse the order of your loops and decrement x instead of incrementing it. I change the code a bit though :

```
int level = 3;
for(int r=level ; r>0 ; r--) {
    for(int c=r ; c>0 ; c--) 
        for (int x=0 ; x<c ; x++)
            System.out.print("*");
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought about it. Thanks for the idea :)

Answer (score 0):

```
        int depth = 3;
        for (int r = depth + 1; r >= 0; r--) {
            for (int c = 0; c < r; c++)
                for (int b = 0; b < c; b++)
                    System.out.print("*");
            System.out.println();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Test
public void reverseTriangle(){
    int num = 3;
    for (int i = num; i > 0; i--) {
        this.draw(i);
        System.out.println();
    }
}

private void draw(int num) {
    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= num; i++) {
        total = total + i;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < total; i++) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
}
```