# Loop error when printing "triangle" of stars

Tags: java, loops

I am trying to print the picture below using nested loops (I should use for & while loops):

```
     **
   ****
 ******
********
```

Starts with 5 spaces, decreasing by 2 each line.
Starts with 2 stars, increasing by 2 each line.
Ends at 4 lines.

My code works on the first line, but it does not print the stars on the remaining 3 lines. Can someone see what the error may be? Please do not give the answer, I just need help understanding the logical error!

```
    int m = 6;
    int n = 0;

    for(int l = 1; l < 5; l++){

        while(m > 0){
            System.out.print(" ");
             m--;
        }
        while(n < (2*l)){
            System.out.print("*");
            n++;
        }
        System.out.println();
        m = 5 - (2*l);
        n = n + 2;
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11409621/creating-a-triangle-with-for-loops

Comment: Please read tag descriptions before including them in your questions. `asterisk` mean something else. I myself learned this few days past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is that you don't reset the `n` variable each loop. You add 2 to it after the first loop at which point is is already larger than `2 * l` so no more stars will be printed.

It would be more sensible to structure it as:

```
for (int l = 0; l < 4; l ++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5 - 2l; i++) 
        System.out.print(" ");
    for (int i = 0; i < 2 + 2l; i++)
        System.out.print("*");
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hint: 
look at m=5 - (2×l);

as soon as l=3
the result will be negativ and the first while-loop wont be executed

Answer (score 0):

Just like you add two to n, you have to remove 2 from m. If I understand quite well, m is your number of spaces and n is your number of stars so if you add two stars; `n+2` then you have to remove the space too so: `m - 2` since the two added stars occupy that space.

```
m = m - 2;
n = n + 2;
```

Edit: you also have to change the while loop where the n is edited, in order not to change the n:

```
int temp = n; 

while(temp > (2*l)){
    System.out.print("*");
            temp++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use nested for loops the outer loop moves down the rows and the inner loop moves along the columns. Each pass through the inner loop should check whether ro place an empty space or an asterisk. This can be done with an if statement  use the integer variables in the for loops to determine when to place a space or an asterisk. The algorithm for this will vary depending on the shape you want.

Alternatively the use of a doubly indexed array might be interesting  here. More complext but maybe something to look at if you need to use a while loop. It might be possible to use for loops to fill a doubly indexed char array with either a " " or a "*" and then simply print out ghe contents of the array while setting the value to null after printing and checking to see if the array is empty or not.

Maybe some of this was helpful. Happy coding.