# Java pyramid display

Tags: java

So this may be a stupid question, but how do you change how a pyramid display is shown? Like I know that in order to get something like this:

```
111111
11111
1111
111
11
1
```

you write

```
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        for(int j=i;j<n;j++)
        {
            System.out.print(" "+ n)}
```

but what would I have to do to get it to be displayed as this:

```
    1
   11
  111
 1111
11111
```

Comment: actually the code you posted doesn't quite give the first result

Comment: did you try checking on google or other stackoverflow questions. check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11409621/creating-a-triangle-with-for-loops. try doing some modifications and play around a bit. Or check this http://www.java.achchuthan.org/2011/01/nested-for-loop-example-to-print.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 static void staircase(int n) {

        //int n = scanner.nextInt();
    int size = n;

   for (int i = 0; i <= size-1; i++){
       for(int j = 5; j > i; j--){
            System.out.print(" ");
       }
        for(int j = 0; j <= i; j++){
            System.out.print("#");
        }
        System.out.println();
   }
```

output would be:

```
     #
    ##
   ###
  ####
 #####
######
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int n = 5;
for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    System.out.println();
    for (int j = i; j < n; j++) {
        System.out.print(" " + n);
    }
}
```

gives

```
5 5 5 5 5 
5 5 5 5
5 5 5
5 5
5
```

But that's messy. It's got 2 for loops. So let's do this instead:

```
String value = "    55555";

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    System.out.println(value.substring(i, i + 5));
}
```

which gives us

```
    5
   55
  555
 5555
55555
```

Just make sure you have enough spaces in the `value` string for it to substring correctly.

Comment: Your second version does not produce the same output that OP is looking for. Notice the alignment. :)

Comment: Blegh, I'll fix it. One sec.

Comment: That's one way to do it. Another way would be to print n number of spaces prior to printing the character.

Comment: @Trobbins I know, but I was too lazy to do the spaces version. Also you'd have to remember to print the right amount of characters after you printed the spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple: just look at the rules how the "1"s and spaces are distributed in the lines. height of the pyramid: `h` line `n`: consists of `h - n` spaces followed by `n` "1"s. Simply translate these rules into code, and it should work.