# Buildng a * Triangle using for loops

Tags: java

```
public class Studying {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i= 0; i<=5; i++){
            for (int q = 4-i; q>=0;){
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for (int w= i; w>0; w++ ){
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.print("*");

            for (int w= i; w<=4; w++ ){
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            for (int q = 4-i; q>=0;){
                System.out.println(" ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to create a triangle using * but there seems to be a continuous loop and I can't figure out where the problem is.

Comment: You never update `q` in your first loop, nor in your last one

Comment: That doesn't matter in this scenario since q=i

Comment: Uh, no. The first time through, i will start out 0 (from the first for loop), and q will start out 4 (4 - i -> 4 - 0 -> 4, in the first inner for loop). 4 is, in fact, >= 0, so you output a space, but then you never modify q, so it's always 4, and the loop just keeps loopin'.

Comment: I believe you are looking for solution that is already posted [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11409621/creating-a-triangle-with-for-loops)

Answer (score 0):

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
   System.out.println("    *********".substring(i, 5 + 2*i));
```

Result:

```
    *
   ***
  *****
 *******
*********
```

Answer (score -1):

Ex:

```
      *
     ***
    *****
   *******
  *********
```

Code:

```
int numberOfRows = 5;
    
for(int i=0; i<numberOfRows; i++)
{
    for(int a=0; a<=numberOfRows; a++)
    {
        int x = numberOfRows - i;
            
        if (a > x) {
           System.out.print("*");
        } else {
           System.out.print(" ");
        }
    }
                
    for(int b=0; b<=i; b++)
    {
        System.out.print("*");
    }

    System.out.print("\n");
}
```