# print stars in JOptionPane.showMessageDialog?

Tags: java

```
import javax.swing.*;

class A1{
  public static void main(String args[]) {

  String z= "";
  String a = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter no");

  int b = Integer.parseInt(a);
  for (int i = 1 ;i <=b ; i++){
  z +=  "*" ;}

  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"\n"+z);
}}
```

Comment: its not woking correctly please help

Comment: what is not working correctly? what are you expecting?

Comment: *
**
***
****
*****
i want pyramid stars

Comment: and what is your current result? do you get an error?

Comment: i am just getting 5 stars in one line like this *****

Comment: so that is what you have programmed. you print as many stars as you enter. how can your program do anything else? what do you mean by pyramid stars?

Comment: you will need at least 2 for loops to make the pyramid

Comment: but its printing correctly in System.out.println with one loop

Comment: You're only constructing the first layer of stars, then immediately printing it. You need another loop to create multiple layers.

Comment: `but its printing correctly in System.out.println with one loop` - yes, because you are printing intermediate results, not the final result of the string. The final result of the sring is what gets displayed in the JOptionPane.

Comment: and if i am printing JOption after loop its only showing me 5 stars.

Comment: @WaseemMubasher, `its only showing me 5 stars.` - and you have been given the reason why.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a triangle with for loops](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11409621/creating-a-triangle-with-for-loops)

Answer (score 0):

You will need multiple loops to display text on a different line.

Don't use string concatenation to build your string.

Something like:

```
String a = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter no");

int b = Integer.parseInt(a);

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0 ; i < b ; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
        sb.append( "*" );
    }

    sb.append("\n");
}

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, sb.toString());
```

Note, this code doesn't work correctly. I'll let you fix the problem with the index ranges.

Another option is to use a JTextArea to display your output in the JOptionPane, then your logic will only need a single loop.

In this case the code would be something like:

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(b, b);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0 ;i <b ; i++)
{
    sb.append("*");
    textArea.append(sb.toString());
    textArea.append("\n");
}

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, textArea); // not sure if
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you want:

```
        for (int i = 1; i <= b; i++)
        {
            for (int y = 1; y <= i; y++)
                z += "*";
            z += "\n";
        }
```