# how to make triangle with ordered number

Tags: javascript

i am making code for java to make triangle ordered number just like this
1
2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9 10 
 
which is using for loops. and i just allowed to input the row only.
if i input 3 and there will be
1
2 3 
4 5 6 
how i can do that? please

```
        var rows= prompt("Jumlah baris");
        var color= prompt("color1:");
        var color1 = prompt("color2:");
        var d = 1;
        var bas = parseInt(rows);
        document.write("<table align=center  width=500 height=500 border=2>");
        for (i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
            document.write("<tr>");
            for (l = 1; l <= i; l++) {
                if ((i + l) % 2 === 1) {
                    document.write("<td bgcolor=" + color + ">" + d + "</td>");
                    d++;
                } else {
                    document.write("<td bgcolor=" + color1 + ">" + d + "</td>");
                    d++;
                }
            }
            document.write("</tr>");
        }
        document.write("</table>");
    </script>
```

Comment: Is this in java or javascript? Your code appears to be javascript.

Comment: I seen this question posted over and over for years.

Comment: @blahfunk yeah  i write in javascript.

Comment: java and javascript have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: @leonasution then you should not tag this "java". They are not the same thing.

Comment: i still cant make the triangle like i want

Comment: You mean like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11409621/creating-a-triangle-with-for-loops)?

Comment: Ah I think I see, his code goes 1 - 12 - 123 he wants 1 - 23 - 456

Comment: no no.with number.but the nuber ordered just like @irkeninvader said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple, really - instead of using a variable inside like you have done, use a variable with a value that goes on increasing.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var rows= prompt("input");
    var t = 1;
    for (i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {

        for (l = 1; l <= i; l++) {
            document.write(t + ' ');
            t++;
        }
        document.writeln(" <br/>");
    }
</script>
```

`t` will go on increasing as we never reset it; it increases alongwith `l`, but never resets.

Comment: Leo might want to add a space after writing the variable: `document.write(t + ' ');` it gets confusing when you get to double digits `1011121314`

Comment: Just helping with his hw :)

Comment: I know it's a hw question, but we're all like that initially. @leonasution Have you taken the [tour](http://www.stackoverflow.com/tour)? Take it.

Comment: No need to apologize, you posted the code you had and were on the right track!

Comment: @leonasution Indeed, some people have just the minimum length of question: 'help me draw a triangle'. That's it. Atleast you have posted something.

Comment: again im sorry for my question.thanks to ikeninvader and cst1992 i was too busy to thinking the table.i will edit the post to my final answer for the homework

Answer (score 1):

When you're doing homework then at least do it in an interesting way.

One loop and 3 lines is all you need:

```
var r = prompt("input")|0;
for (i=1; i<=(r*r+r)/2; i++)
  document.write(i+(Math.sqrt(1+8*i)%2==1?'<br>':' '));
```

See [**DEMO**](https://jsbin.com/sojaqonola/1/edit?js,output).

I'm sure you'll get some extra points for explaining how you came up with such an elegant solution.

Comment: Neat code, sketchy advice.  Overall +Math.sqrt(1+8*1)%2