# Printing Simple Patterns in Java

Tags: java, for-loop, nested-loops

Could someone explain the basics behind printing simple patterns in Java?

I'll give one specific example.

I'd just like for someone to clarify what each line is doing so I get a better understanding of how this works. Any other explained examples (line by line) would also be appreciated!

```
public static void drawPyramidPattern() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5 - i; j++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for (int k = 0; k <= i; k++) {
            System.out.print("* ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: why not use a debugger and step through it?

Comment: Do debugging and go line by line. Then you will get what is happening

Comment: Right out the algorithm on paper. You  should understand for loops and print statements individually at this point in your learning

Comment: take a paper and pen maintain table of variables and go through the code to see flow of control changing values of variables

Comment: your user name makes more sense than your question :p just kidding

Comment: By the way, try not to take the downvotes personally, just that it's somewhat unclear what you've attempted to understand about this code already

Comment: @cricket_007 Thank you, I just don't have a very good handle on how to print patterns in Java and was hoping someone could explain what each for loop was doing. I didn't even think to use the debugger since I'm fairly new at this. I will keep that in mind next time before posting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a triangle with for loops](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11409621/creating-a-triangle-with-for-loops)

Comment: Personally, I'd recommend focusing on what's needed to print an individual line rather than the whole pattern at first, then examine any numeric patterns you see with the input. Note: it'll require some math

Comment: unfortunately you need to learn things, can't depend everytime for these

Comment: and here is one tip for these loops why don't you put some `#,$,%` or anything instead of space, so you can see how this is working and what are you trying to hide (won't be that hard and you won't need debugger too) ;)

Comment: First learn single loop.... then try nested loops <br />

for single loops see this animation to understand flow of execution:-
https://blog.penjee.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/top-5-programming-animated-gifs_demonstration-of-while-loop-animation_logo.gif

Answer (score 0):

Printing anything or everything via a loop is just about understanding the flow of execution. In your code also, if you'll start watching the flow line by line you'll come to know that how it is working exactly.

If you understand how it works, you would be able to print any pattern, but basics should be clear. Try printing variable i, j and k values after each iteration. See the values that how that gets changed after each cycle of execution and then see the logic you've applied.

Your question is somewhat very broad in scope and can not be answered exactly unless narrowed it down. I would suggest to run this line by line and watch the output, try more changes even if it doesn't make any sense, you'll be having a good understanding over looping even for all of your future tasks. And if after trying yourself, you come to any problem, share here, people are ready to solve them. :)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

**First you must a have complete understanding of loops, nested loops then you come up to patterns designing.**

> 1) First run the loops in hard form like on Register/on Page for understanding the loops.
>   2) Use debugger to identify the loop progress.

Answer (score 0):

If you think about it in terms of mathematics, loops are just functions.

A single for loop would just be x.

Example

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
System.out.println("This is function x.");
}
```

However when you start nesting loops it because a greater function. A for loop inside another for loop would be a function x^2

For example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
     for (int j = 0; J < 5; j++){
     System.out.println("This is the j loop");
     }
     System.out.println("This is the i loop");
}
```

The reason behind this is because in order to finish the first iteration of i, everything inside the loop must be completed. But, the i loop has another loop inside of it, so that must be finished first. So the loop with j must execute until it is finished. (In this case 5 times), Great, now we can increment i. But now we have to step through j again! This process continues until i reaches its threshold of being < 5. So the output would look something like this

```
Output:
This is the j loop
This is the j loop
This is the j loop
This is the j loop
This is the j loop
This is the i loop
This is the j loop
This is the j loop
....
```

This would continue until the i has reached 5, in which case it no longer satisfies the necessary i < 5, and the loop would end. Hopefully this helps

Answer (score 0):

First, since i = 0 & 0<5 is true you enter the first(outer) for-loop.

Remember i = 0.

Then j = 0; but 0 < i = 0 is false so you don't enter the second loop.

For the third loop, k = 0 & 0<=0 is true. So you enter the loop and execute the print statement, i.e print a star.

k++, this will increment k by 1 and check the boolean; You ask yourself is 1 <= 0; clearly no ; so you exit the for-loop and then reach the println statement which will take you to the next line.

And then you go back to the outer loop.

Answer (score 0):

//this code print Diagonal Pattern if matrix is 
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
output is :
1
4 2
7 5 3
8 6
9

```
import java.util.*;
class DiagonalPattern
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int x[][];
        int i,j,row,col,p,temp=1,last=0;
        System.out.println("how many array wants to create and size of array");
        row=sc.nextInt();
        col=sc.nextInt();
        x=new int[row][col];
        System.out.println("Enter  " +row*col+ "  elements of array of array");
            for(i=0;i<row;i++)
            {
            for(j=0;j<col;j++)
            {
                x[i][j]=sc.nextInt();
                last=j;
            }
            }
        for(i=0;i<row;i++)
            {
            System.out.println("");
            int k=i;
            for(j=0;j<=i;j++,k--)
            {
                if(j==col)
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.print(x[k][j]);  
                System.out.print(" ");
                }
            }
            }
        for(p=x.length;p>0;p--,temp++)
            {
            System.out.println("");
            i=x.length-1;
            int k=i;
            for(j=temp;j<=last;j++,k--)
            {
                System.out.print(x[k][j]);  
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            }   
    }
}
```