# How to make this triangle shape with letters in java?

Tags: java

Could someone please show how to make the following figure with for loops.

I can basically make this pattern with stars and other characters - but I cannot
figure out how to do this with letters to save my life.

```
     m
    rma
   ormat
  formati
 nformatik
informatika
```

Comment: Show us what you tried yourself. This is not a free homework service.

Comment: Again, I know how too do the triangle shape with stars and spaces but I just cannot figure how to do this with letters - tried many things but did not come close.

Comment: Again: you ask us to provide homework style information to you. That will only happen when you show us what you have tried. And hint: first clarify your requirements. It is not about characters, but parts of a certain word, isn't it?

Comment: GhostCat would you mind if I answer it?

Comment: @AndrewWatson, we frown upon (and sometimes downvote) answers that give the code away for free to askers that haven’t shown a decent effort on their part. On the other hand I would much welcome an answer in plain English that outlined an algorithm and possibly mentioned which control statement, which class/es and/or method/s to use and left it to the asker to write the code.

Comment: Please everyone refer to [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: I didn’t find the exact same question when I searched, it’s probably there somewhere. Here’s a similar one that you can probably use for some inspiration: [Creating a triangle with for loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11409621/creating-a-triangle-with-for-loops).

Comment: I am thinking a `String`, a `for` loop and either `String.charAt()` or possibly simpler, `String.substring()`. It will require some effort to find the correct arithmetical expression for the value/s you want to pass to the method/s.

Answer (score 0):

In your head — or on a piece of paper — number the lines in the desired output backwards from 5 down to 0:

```
5      m
4     rma
3    ormat
2   formati
1  nformatik
0 informatika
```

Now have a `for` loop count down from 5 to 0; each time through the loop should print one line. Can a `for` loop count backwards? Certainly. You will find many examples out there, so if this is not clear, go search.

To print each line, you first need to print some spaces, then some letters. How many spaces on each line, given you have assigned it a line number as I suggested? To print the spaces you can either use another `for` loop inside the first `for` loop, or a little more tricky, but also shorter, you may use `"              ".substring(beginIndex, endIndex)` to take a substring of a string of spaces. To print the letters, take a substring of `"informatika"`. From which index? And the slightly harder part, to which index? I think you will need to subtract two numbers to get the right value.