# Q: How to write to the right side of the triangle?

Tags: java

I started learning java, and that's my question :
How to write to the right side of the triangle?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Triangle {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("please enter your siz triangle :");
        int lines = scanner.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i <= lines; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < i; j++) {
                System.out.println("*");
            }

        }

        scanner.close();

    }

}
```

for 5 i get:

```
*
*
*
*
*
```

Comment: what do you mean by write to the right side of the triangle? do you want a right angle triangle towards right side?

Comment: `System.out.println` always prints on a new line, to continue writing ont the same line use `System.out.print`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating a triangle with for loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11409621/creating-a-triangle-with-for-loops)

Comment: I solved the problem thanks to all the assistants (tnx @jAc)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this, use two loops first one to print the number of spaces and then second to print the number of stars based on the number of rows inputted by user. This prints the complete triangle :

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("please enter your siz triangle :");
    int n = scanner.nextInt();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = n - i; j > 1; j--) {
            // printing spaces
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
            // printing stars
            System.out.print("* ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    scanner.close();
```

Comment: first of all - tnx! I wrote as you suggested and that's the result
*
  
*
*
 
*
*
*

Comment: @Avinadav Great, glad to help. then you can accept this answer

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, you need to know how to print. And small correction in `for` loop indexes. Starting `j` with `1` will lose one row. I set it to 0 and starting `i` with `1`

```
for (int i = 1; i <= lines; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Input:

```
3
```

Output:

```
*
**
***
```